# Objective C - Custom Getter with inheritance

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, getter-setter

Recently I have worked with Core Data. When I want to set a default value for some fields, I came up with this problem:

So I made a simple represent:

We have 2 class Parent and Child, in which Child inherit from Parent.

```
// Parent.h
@interface Parent : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;



// Child.h
@interface Child : Parent
```

In Parent class, I made a custom getter to set a default value when nothing is set:

```
// Parent.h
- (NSString *)lastName
{
    if (_lastName) {
        return _lastName;
    } else {
        return @"Parent Default Name";
    }
}
```

But I cannot make a custom default value for the field "name" which Child inherits from its Parent.

```
// Child.h
@implementation Child

- (NSString *)lastName
{
    if (super.lastName) {
        return super.lastName;
    } else {
        return @"Child Default Name";
    }
}
```

The main function to test:
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

```
    @autoreleasepool {
        Parent *newParent = [[Parent alloc] init];
        newParent.lastName = @"newParentName";
        NSLog(@"Parent: %@", newParent.lastName);

        Child *newChild =  [[Child alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Child: %@", newChild.lastName);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Apparently, @"Child Default Name" is never reach. The returned values would be @"Parent Default Name".
So my question here is: How can I set a custom getter for the field the Child class inherits from Parent without define an overriding property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// Parent.h

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
{
   NSString *_lastName; //just add this line.
}


@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;
```

If you want another name to use, you can try this:

```
// Parent.h
@interface Parent : NSObject
{
   NSString *_lastNameAlias; //can be used in child
}


@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;

//Parent.m
@synthesize lastName = _lastNameAlias;
```

// Parent.m

```
- (NSString *)lastName
{
    if (!_lastName) {
        _lastName =  @"Parent Default Name";
    } 

    return _lastName;
}
```

// Child.m

```
- (NSString *)lastName
{
    if (!_lastName) { //Or _lastNameAlias
        _lastName =  @"Child Default Name";
    } 

    return _lastName;
}
```

And as Steven Fisher mentioned, `lastname` is different with `lastName`, but I think it is a spelling mistake.

Comment: hi simalone, I want to use the same variable in Parent and Child. I also tried your suggestion, but the returned value still @"Parent Default Name". Can you recheck with the updated question. Thank you.

Comment: thanks simalone, it works. :)
May I ask: what is the purpose of declaration "NSString *_lastName;" in Parent.h?

Comment: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSStrng *lastName;` will help to define  a `NSStrng *_lastName` automatically. But default it can not be seen by child, define it manually in .h file will change it to `protect` and be visible for child.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

```
- (NSString *)lastname
```

vs

```
- (NSString *)lastName
```

Objective-C is case sensitive. Make sure they have the same case and the behaviour you want should happen automatically.

That said, calling `self.lastName` is pretty weird (assuming you settle on `lastName` for both). I'm not sure that will work. I suggest calling `[super lastName]` instead.

Comment: thank you Steven, it's a typo mistake, I updated the code and the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the parent implementation of the `lastName` method never returns `nil`. It either returns the current (non-nil) value of _lastName or it returns the default parent string. In neither case does it return `nil`.  Hence the `if [super.lastName]` check will always return true.

To avoid the problem, the child getter needs to access the instance variable directly. This can only be done if the parent class explicitly declares the instance variable in the header file.  So `parent.h` should be

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
{
    NSString *_lastName;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lastname;
@end
```

and then the implementation in `child.m` can be

```
- (NSString *)lastname
{
    if ( _lastName )
        return( _lastName );
    else
        return  @"Child default name";
}
```

Comment: hi user3386109, thank you for your time. The problem is checking super.lastName will always TRUE, and I can't seem to find a solution for this. :)

Comment: @anhdat Ya super.lastName will always be true because as user3386109 said when super.lastName is called the parent class will either return a value which has been set or it'll return a default value that means your super.lastName will always have a value so it can't go to else part....